# Phone Interview, Applications, and Social Media

Tags: interviewing, social-media

I just had a phone interview. When answering a question about why I applied there, I said that I admired their activities on social media.

But the application came first (out of necessity) and the social media appreciation came after that when I was researching the position.

I was just trying to find something that sounded good and not desperate, and now I'm sure I just bombed that interview just like I have done at every other one I've had for the past year.

I forget the right things to say when I'm nervous.

Comment: IMHO, "Why did you apply here?" is the stupidest question you can possibly ask an interviewee. Both the interviewer and the interviewee know that 99% of the time, no matter what answer is given, the real answer is "Because I need a job and you're hiring."

Comment: @A.R. That's not universally true, really depends on company size. For startups/scaleups this is something you will be failed on rather swiftly lots of the time, because at that size you need to care about the mission. Those really are not places for just a paycheck.

Comment: OP: is there a question somewhere you wanna ask? So far this just seems like a bit of a rant.

Comment: @AidaPaul Oh, sure, you'll get failed on that question anywhere for providing the wrong answer. Somehow our culture entertains the idea that there are things you're just supposed to lie about, and this is one of them.

Comment: Just wanted to know if that was a deal breaker, because I know that your views of social media get documented.

Comment: Is it lying though A.R? If it's a startup, often with the expectation of long hours, then going there "just to get paid" is probably a bad idea

Comment: @A.R. Gotta disagree with you on that one as well... I mean, clearly I wouldn't work where I do right now if they weren't paying me, money is a big factor in choosing where I work... but to be honest, its not the biggest factor. No one I work for would pay me less then I need. And other things, work life balance, working for a company that has a positive impact on the world and has some very outdated opinions on how to treat employees/customers/and suppliers (IE treating them with respect)... hard to find.

Comment: @Questor I'd agree with you about that, except those aren't the sorts of things you usually find out until _after_ the interview.

Comment: Glassdoor and linkedin exist. Publicly traded companies post income statistics which includes their turnover rate... The internet is a very powerful tool.... Also you can ask questions during an inteview... Such as "What does the average work week look like? Do you have paternity leave? What are the benefits... etc... Yes some companies don't like it when you ask those questions... But the companies that don't like it have bad benefits, no paternity leave, bad working hours etc... Interviews are a 2 way street. They are interviewieng you, and you are interviewing them.

Answer (score 5):

If the question is as per this comment:

> Just wanted to know if that was a deal breaker, because I know that
> your visits to social media get documented

Then: No. There is not remotely any chance than an interviewer is going to encode your verbal response to this open-ended question, check it against a social media database, and cross-check against when the job offer was posted, to identify some half-truth on this trivial point.